# Select whole table but unique value in a specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, group-by, distinct, aggregation

Please help me with an issue that I have come across during work. I'm working with SQL Server, and I'm aware that using cursors I could achieve this, but I'm pretty sure that there is a way of doing it using simple query in SQL, but my brain bulb doesn't want to turn on. Let me explain my issue with an example.

I have got a table like this:

```
postedby    |   date        |   comment |
1           |   01.01.2012  |   sth sth |
2           |   01.01.2012  |   sth sth |
3           |   01.01.2012  |   sth sth |
2           |   01.01.2012  |   sth sth |
3           |   02.01.2012  |   sth sth |
2           |   03.01.2012  |   sth sth |
2           |   05.01.2012  |   sth sth |
```

What I want to accomplish is get all the posts but one for every user (postedby column), the date must be the latest and of course show the comment.

I have tried doing:

```
Select distinct postedby, date, comment
```

but didn't work, as I understand distinct works for every column, so if in 2 rows postedby is the same but comment is different it will treat it as distincts

I have tried doing:

`Select postedby,date,comment group by postedby` (don't bother about the from clause)
giving me the error or aggregation, so I tried
`select postedby,min(date) group by postedby` - of course works, but I can't get the comment.

Should I use in some way aggregated queries? Or what am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like today is the RowNumber function day!!
If all you needed is the latest date and comment for each post:

```
SELECT postedBy, date, comment
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY postedby, ORDER BY date DESC) AS RowNumber, 
             postedBy, date, comment
      FROM MyTable) t 
WHERE RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: A question, I know that is works with oracle, but with sql server?

Comment: @UdoFholl - This will work for SQL Server 2005+, so I'm holding up my +1 for when op clarifies what SQL Server version is using

Comment: @Lamak well let's hope it's 2005+ then :D

Comment: @BassamMehanni: you don't need the join. You can put the row_number() function with all needed columns into a single select and then wrap that with a `select * from ( ... )  where rownumber = 1` (where ... is the inner select from about). That will be faster because the table will only be scanned once.

Comment: @UdoFholl: That statement will work with Oracle, PostgreSQL, DB2, Sybase and Teradata.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that's how I had it, but I went back to the question, and I noticed that he wanna get all the records but for the date, and comment he just want the latest, that's why he need a join

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I added it back in the solution just so that in case I misunderstood what the OP is trying to achieve

Comment: @BassamMehanni: hmm. I think your first solution would fullfill the requirements of the question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name alright sold .. I re-read it again and looks like u r right .. not sure what throw me off

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for the time you put in my question, well Bassam's solution worked, I'm using SQL Server 2005 :) BTW when I used this query I got like repeated X time the same row, I wrote Select Distinct to output what exactly I wanted, do you know maybe why is this happening?
@Bassam Thank you, I never heard about this type of built-in functions (Ranking functions) I still pretty new to "programming" under SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You tried `min(date)`. It will return min date of unique value. Have you tried `max(date)`? It will be better for that. The max date always return the latest date.

Comment: Ohh sorry, I just noticed it, well as I tried to clarify, it isn't about which function I'm using, or if I didn't write "FROM table_name", it was about using an aggregate function, and wanting to get a column value which doesn't require an aggregate fun. ;) the answer is already up ;) but thanks for the effort and time :)